# Problems debugging C++ Android native code in Eclipse (Native-Audio example)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to understand the inner workings of the Native-Audio example that comes with the NDK. To do this I'd like to step through the C code in a debug mode, but I've been having several issues attempting to do this. Here are the steps I am taking:

1) In Eclipse, File -> New -> Android Project from Existing Code. I select the Native-Audio directory and select the option to copy it to my workspace. No issues here, and if I select the project and Run, it runs on my connected Android device no problem.

2) I select the project and do "Convert to a C/C++ Project". Next I go into the Project Properties and use `ndk-build.cmd` instead of `make` as the Build command. Again, no issues here, and if I build/run the project it works fine.

3) I open the "native-audio-jni.c" file in the C/C++ Perspective. Here is where the problems start. Immediately I get a ton of errors referring to unresolved types. Now with these errors (which did not exist before opening the file for editing) I cannot build/run the project. The only workaround I have found for this is to disable everything under Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis. When I do this I am able to build/run the project again.

4) Next, I set a breakpoint in the "native-audio-jni.c" file, specifically in the `selectClip` function. I then follow the instructions found here: http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin and add `NDK_BUILD=1` to my Build command. Now when I try and build, I get this error:

```
ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=1 all 
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : native-audio-jni <= native-audio-jni.c
jni/native-audio-jni.c: In function 'bqRecorderCallback':
jni/native-audio-jni.c:136:5: error: 'bqRecorderBufferQueue' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:136:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/native-audio-jni/native-audio-jni.o] Error 1
```

If I remove `NDK_DEBUG=1` from the Build command this doesn't appear during build and the app runs fine. I've also tried following these instructions: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/. However, when I include `android:debuggable="true"` to my manifest file and click "Debug", the same error as above occurs.

I'm quite unfamiliar with JNI/NDK, and can't figure out the issues here. I apologize for the long post but just wanted to be thorough in explaining the steps I've taken. Any help would be very much appreciated.